# Using an accessor method in Java's switch statement

Tags: java, methods, switch-statement

I have several `switch` statements in a Java program. My question is, if I construct the `switch` statement similar to this:

```
switch (getNum()) {
    case 0: // do something
    case 1: // do something
    ...
}
```

where the variable to be switched is getting returned from an accessor method (aka 'getter' method), will the switch statement call `getNum()` every time it checks a case? Or will it assign a temporary variable to the `int` being returned from `getNum()` to check each case?

Comment: Just as an aside, consider that putting a `System.out.println ("called")` inside your `getNum()` takes less key-strokes than your query above.

Comment: Ha, true... that could have saved me some time...

Comment: It also takes a lot less time and gives you the right answer 100% of the time. A forum might give you no answer, or the wrong answer, or several mutually contradictory answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> will the switch statement call getNum() every time it checks a case?

It doesn't 'check each case' at all. It evaluates the expression once and jumps to the associated case immediately, via one of several techniques depending on the implementation.

> Or will it assign a temporary variable to the int being returned from getNum() to check each case?

It doesn't do that either: see above.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "It jumps to the case immediately"? Or am I just reading it in a smart-ass way, so it technically doesn't "jump" to the case?

Comment: As I said, the actual technique depends on the implementation, and also on the density or sparsity of the case values. Indexed jump tables are the most common technique, but I have also seen compilers use binary chops.

Answer (score 2):

> will the switch statement call getNum() every time it checks a case? Or will it assign a temporary variable to the int being returned from getNum() to check each case?

The `getNum()` expression will be evaluated once only.  For the details of the semantics, refer to [JLS section 14.11](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11)

(And in fact, a switch statement *typically* gets compiled to code that won't test the value against each of the cases.  But that depends on the number and spread of the cases, and details of the Java compiler(s).)

---

> What do you mean when you say "It jumps to the case immediately"?

The "trick" at the (native) machine code level is to create a table of the branch addresses for the different cases.  Then use the value of the switch expression to index into the table.  In pseudocode it is something like this:

```
  value = evaluate(expression)
  branchAddress = switchTable[value]
  jump(branchAddress)
```

As you can see, this avoids doing a series of tests on the `value`.  But the downside is that if the range of switch case values is large you can end up with a large switch table.  Hence my caveats above: the JIT compiler needs to decide whether to compile the switch this way or as a sequence of tests, or using a combination of the two approaches.

Comment: @EJP - I'm talking about (native) machine code, not bytecodes.